# Specifying charset in HTTP header with Lighttpd

Tags: character-encoding, debian, mime-types, lighttpd

I'm trying to specify a charset in the HTTP header of my Lighttpd-setup. I've tried numerous suggestions I've found throughout StackExchange's websites.

**1.** Tried looking in the `mime.types` file, so I could just add `; charset=utf-8` at the end of whatever file-types I wanted to specify a charset for in the HTTP header, but the mime.types-file is looking nothing like I expected: http://pastebin.com/QMKJ8Lqj

**2.** Tried changing *`create-mime.assign.pl`* from this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
open MIMETYPES, "/etc/mime.types" or exit;
print "mimetype.assign = (\n";
my %extensions;
while(<MIMETYPES>) {
  chomp;
  s/\#.*//;
  next if /^\w*$/;
  if(/^([a-z0-9\/+-.]+)\s+((?:[a-z0-9.+-]+[ ]?)+)$/) {
    foreach(split / /, $2) {
      # mime.types can have same extension for different
      # mime types
      next if $extensions{$_};
      $extensions{$_} = 1;
      print "\".$_\" => \"$1\",\n";
    }
  }
}
print ")\n";
```

Into this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
open MIMETYPES, "/etc/mime.types" or exit;
print "mimetype.assign = (\n";
my %extensions;
while(<MIMETYPES>) {
  chomp;
  s/\#.*//;
  next if /^\w*$/;
  if(/^([a-z0-9\/+-.]+)\s+((?:[a-z0-9.+-]+[ ]?)+)$/) {
    my $pup = $1;
    foreach(split / /, $2) {
      # mime.types can have same extension for different
      # mime types
      next if $extensions{$_};
      next if not defined $pup;
      next if $pup eq '';
      $extensions{$_} = 1;
      if ($pup =~ /^text\//) {
        print "\".$_\" => \"$pup; charset=utf-8\",\n";
      } else {
        print "\".$_\" => \"$pup\",\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
print ")\n";
```

And restarted the Lighttpd server afterwards - nothing.

**3.** Afterwards I tried adding the following to the *`lighttpd.conf`* file:

```
mimetype.assign = (
  ".css" => "text/css; charset=utf-8",
  ".html" => "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  ".htm" => "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  ".js" => "text/javascript; charset=utf-8",
  ".text" => "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  ".txt" => "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  ".xml" => "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
)
```

And it gave me an error that it couldn't restart the Lighttpd server, because it found duplicate config variables of the "mimetype.assign" variable - one in create-mime.assign.pl and one in lighttpd.conf. I know I could try by removing `include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"` from lighttpd.conf, so that there isn't any duplicate config variables, but what about all the other mime-types?

***General info:***

- Lighttpd version: 1.4.28
- PHP version: 5.3.29-1
- Linux: Debian 6.0 Squeeze
- Lighttpd.conf: http://pastebin.com/N6GrdUsi

Answer (score 1):

Please try a newer version of lighttpd.
I am looking at 1.4.36 and `doc/scripts/create-mime.conf.pl` contains a list of extensions to which it appends "; charset=utf-8"

```
# text/* subtypes to serve as "text/...; charset=utf-8"
# text/html IS NOT INCLUDED: html has its own method for defining charset
#   (<meta>), but the standards specify that content-type in HTTP wins over
#   the setting in the html document.
my %text_utf8 = map { $_ => 1 } qw(    # ......
```

You can find it in the git sources: https://github.com/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/blob/master/doc/scripts/create-mime.conf.pl

Comment: lighttpd 1.4.45-1 on Debian 9 does not ship that file. `/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl` does not have any utf-8 handling.

Comment: Debian package lighttpd 1.4.52-2 uses create-mime.conf.pl and that (or a later version) will be part of Debian Buster.